# class init using ARC ... unexpected array deallocation while using + convenience method instead of - init

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsarray, automatic-ref-counting

this is a stupid question but it's driving me crazy!!

I have a simple ARC class that implements 2 NSMutableSet and 1 NSMutableArray. These 3 variables are private so they are not exposed using @property but I know that, by default, the object var of the class are defined as __strong.

Problem is that in a certain time of future a class method, -(id)drawObject, access internally to the NSMutableArray and it crashes as soon as the method access to the _outObjects var. So debugging seams that the NSMutableArray initialized inside the init is gone (I'm able to read it inside init, it's empty obviously, but I can't read it inside drawObject because is deallocated.)

The problem could be solved changing the init line from

```
_outObjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:_objects.count];
```

to

```
_outObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:_objects.count];
```

but I expected the same result using ARC!! Apple say that the + init methods and - init methods are the same using ARC! It should change only the way as the preprocessor completes the class.

Declaring NSMutableArray *_outObjects; as NSMutableArray __strong *_outObjects; is obviously useless because it already is by default.

Here the header

```
@interface GTGameBag : NSObject {

@protected
    NSMutableSet *_objects; 

    NSMutableSet *_innerObjects;
    NSMutableArray *_outObjects;
}

- (id)initWithObjects:(NSSet*)objects;
- (id)drawObject;
```

and here the implementation

```
- (id)initWithObjects:(NSSet *)objects {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _objects = [objects mutableCopy];

        _outObjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:_objects.count];
        _innerObjects = [_objects mutableCopy];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)drawObject {
    id obj = [_innerObjects anyObject];
    [_innerObjects removeObject:obj];
    [_outObjects addObject:obj];

    return obj;
}
```

How is possible this different behavior using ARC while allocating an empty array using the + and the - method?

Thank you in advance.
Gabriele.

Comment: Are you sure you're using ARC in this file?  Try putting in `[self retain]`.  If you get an error on `retain`, you are using ARC.  If you don't get an error, you're not using ARC.

Comment: Unbelievable!!! ... it was super simple but I did not see it. My mistake was to set true the Objective-C++ ARC LLVM warning instead of Objective-C ARC into the LLVM Language section. I didn't double check it. aaaah!! Thank you so much!!!